# Which technology stacks to use to develop app for Android or iOS

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-functions, architecture

I am about to begin to build an app and I have choosen to develop the app in Flutter, and connected it to Firebase. However this is where I struggle to understand what Firebase does. My intial thought was to use Flutter -> node.js(host API and backend logic) -> mongoDB

But I see that if I implement Firebase it would be easier for scalability, authentication, microservices and a lot more

if I use Firebase, where would I connect node.js in the implementation to handle the logic of the app, as I do not want to add the logic in Flutter.

Just want to confirm wether I am thinking right,  I connect flutter directly to Firebase database (all authentication authorization is handled by Firebase) And from there I need to write a logic to whenever push a notification to user. Can I write the logic in Firebase?

Comment: Firebase hosts files and does not provide dynamic content. You can connect your Firebase app to services such as Cloud Run where you can run your Node.js code. This link will help: https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/cloud-run

Comment: You can execute JS code in Firebase's Cloud Functions. To send a push notification to a device, for example, you can send that notification from a cloud function and then handle whatever logic you want in that function. Firebase Cloud Functions operate in the Node.JS environment and the default language for scripting them is JavaScript, so Firebase seems like a perfect fit for your project.

Comment: @trndjc thanks for the input, for how I see the application working is like this

Flutter sends data to firebase -> Firebase_database all of the data gets stored there -> Firebase_cloud_functions To handle the logic of the application

would it be possible that to set Firebase cloud function before firebase database, so that we process the data before we insert it to the database? 

Flutter sends data to firebase -> Firebase_cloud_functions To handle the logic of the application and process the data -> Firebase_database all of the data from Firebase_cloud_functions gets stored here.

Comment: You can absolutely do that. You can either call the cloud function directly from the client, and pass it whatever data the function needs, and the function can do whatever you program it to do before adding it to to the database (in the cloud function). You can also create trigger functions in the cloud, which will run automatically when certain actions are taken in the database. For example, if you had a collection of users, you could write a cloud function that would be called automatically (by the db) whenever a new user document is created created, deleted, or updated in that collection.

Comment: Just realize that if you update the database through cloud functions, meaning that the client calls a cloud function in the server and that function ultimately updates the database, you lose the offline-capability of Firestore on the client. You will always need an internet connection when calling functions in the cloud. However, if you interface with the database directly from the client, you don't need a steady internet connection to execute tasks--tasks are recorded when the device is offline and executed the moment connection is restored.

Comment: @trndjc For my app to work, the user needs to have active internet connection to receive alerts and give alerts to other users.  So I do not think that having offline-capability would do any damage, or am I overlooking anything?

I also guess that I could implement that some part of the client function that just directly contacts the firebase database, such as authentication or other functions.

Comment: What is the concern around interacting with the database directly from the client? It's faster and cheaper than going through a cloud function, and you maintain offline-capability, which is a really nice feature. I would default to the client interacting with the database when coding this app and only go through a cloud function when there is a good reason to.